How to enable jackson custom serialiser in micronaut?
I have usecase to enable custom serialization for one of the field. I'm trying to implement the same using below snippet.
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
private CustomDTO customDto;

Error says :
java: Annotation @JsonSerialize specifies attribute 'contentUsing'. Currently supported attributes include: [as]
Any other alternative way to introduce custom serialization in micronaut ?
Exact scenario :
Need to introduce custom serialiser / deserialiser in cosmos db read. Azure cosmos uses jackson for the same. Need to introduce the custom serialiser here. But seems like using attribute is not supported in micronaut ? ()
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
private CustomDTO customDto;


I assume you are using Micronaut Serde, which doesn't implement all the features Jackson provides. You can implement a global customerDTO Serde.
@Singleton
public class CustomerDTOSerde implements Serde<CustomerDTO> {

    @Override
    public @Nullable CustomerDTO deserialize(
            @NonNull Decoder outerDecoder,
            @NonNull DecoderContext context,
            @NonNull Argument<? super CustomerDTO> type)
            throws IOException {

        try (Decoder innerDecoder = outerDecoder.decodeObject(type)) {

            String key = innerDecoder.decodeKey();
            String fieldA = null

            while (key != null) {

                if ( Objects.equals("fieldA2, key)) {
                        fieldA = innerDecoder.decodeString();
            } else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown key " + key);
            }
            key = innerDecoder.decodeKey();
        }

        return new CustomerDTO(fieldA);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(
            @NonNull Encoder encoder,
            @NonNull EncoderContext context,
            @NonNull Argument<? extends CustomerDTO> type,
            @NonNull CustomerDTO value)
            throws IOException {
        try (Encoder objectEncoder = encoder.encodeObject(type)) {
            objectEncoder.encodeKey("fieldA");
            objectEncoder.encodeString(value.getFieldA());
            //..
        }
    }
}

The example above assumes that you have a CustomerDTO containing a single property fieldA.

Thanks for the response. I assume azure-cosmos uses jackson for serialisation and this micronaut interception will not have an impact. I tried add this but no luck.
